# MATLAB's hmmtrain assumes initial transition from state 1

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-models

The MATLAB statistics toolbox function hmmtrain.m appears to assume that the model is initially in state 1 before the training sequence.  Is there any way to turn off this "feature"?  An example:

```
>> y = [ 3 3 1 2 3 ];
>> H = eye( 3 );
>> T = ones(3)/3;
>> [ T, H ] = hmmtrain( y, T, H )

T =

         0    0.5000    0.5000
         0         0    1.0000
    0.5000         0    0.5000


H =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

The training set includes no transitions from 1 to 3.  Why is T(1,3) non-zero?!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure because I don't have Matlab on the computer in front of me, but it looks like you want to fit a model with known states, rather than unknown. [Mathworks suggests using `hmmestimate()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/hmmestimate.html) in that situation. While I fully agree that the output you're showing is a really dumb thing for Matlab to do, maybe trying `hmmestimate()` will get you on the right track in the meantime?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, EMS.  Despite appearances, I really do want to in general learn just from emitted symbols that are not the same as the states.  I used H=eye(3) in the above example to make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the following wrapper function for hmmtrain that creates a special state 1 that is only used for the initial state of the model.  From the outside caller's point of view it doesn't exist and you only get statistics of the transitions between the symbols of your training sequence; it learns nothing regarding the initial state of the system.

```
  % MYHMMTRAIN - Wrapper on HMMTRAIN that removes "initial state" effects

  function [ T, H ] = myhmmtrain( y, T, H, varargin )

  % hmmtrain assumes the system always starts in state 1, 
  % so we create a "state 1" that isn't used for anything else
  N = size(T,1);
  T = [ 0           ones(1,N)/N; ...
        zeros(N,1)  T ];
  M = size(H,2);
  H = [ zeros(1,M); H ];

  % train
  [ T, H ] = hmmtrain( y, T, H, varargin{:} );

  % remove false state 1
  T = T(2:end,2:end);
  H = H(2:end,:);

  end
```